# How could be done algorithm for rectangle collisions in C#

Tags: c#, algorithm, collision-detection

How could be done algorithm for `Rectangle` collisions on canvas in C#?

And which values of **X,Y** we should apply to avoid that collision?

Basically I have got two `Rectangle` in `List` so I just have to detect if there is a collision between them.

I am not sure if this is useful code **The Liang-Barsky algorithm for line-rectangle collisions** https://gist.github.com/ChickenProp/3194723

Thank you in advance!

[image]

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please show us your attempt.

Comment: @Stefan I have no clue where do I have to start...

Comment: @JonathanCarroll I have no clue where do I have to start... Sorry

Comment: Do you want a raw implementation or a ready to use function? C# System.Windows.Rect has a method called IntersectsWith.

Comment: @ViniciusZaramella Sounds great! I need any ready method, no raw code. Thanx!

Comment: @Dimi, I posted a answer, if it solves your problem could mark it as a answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use System.Windows.Rect.IntersectsWith. Try it like this:

```
Rect rect1 = new Rect(left1, top1, widht1, height1);
Rect rect2 = new Rect(left2, top2, widht2, height2);

bool intersects = rect1.IntersectsWith(rect2);
```